# SQLcipher (different versions) works on one platform , but crash on other platform

Tags: android, android-ndk, x86, arm, sqlcipher

I have strange problem with SQLcipher build for ARM/x86 device.

When I crypt database with version 2.1.1 and build it with Gradle for ARM and x86 (fat client), it run correctly on ARM device, but on x86 throws error

> "No implementation found for native
>   Lnet/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteDatabase;.native_key ([C)V"

When I repeat previous steps with version 2.2.2, it runs on x86, but on ARM it throws previous error.

With version 3.1.0 is result same as version 2.2.2

Can you help me solve it ?

This is content of built apk file (filtered res files):

```
unzip -l SKG-fat-debug-unaligned.apk | grep -v res/
Archive:  SKG-fat-debug-unaligned.apk
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
   113664  05-03-14 22:32   assets/enc.db
  2305475  05-03-14 22:32   assets/icudt46l.zip
    11937  05-04-14 21:17   assets/postupy.json
     7988  05-04-14 21:17   AndroidManifest.xml
   228184  05-04-14 21:10   resources.arsc
  4348908  05-03-14 22:32   classes.dex
    11358  05-04-14 21:17   META-INF/LICENSE.txt
      301  05-04-14 21:17   META-INF/NOTICE.txt
    38544  05-04-14 21:17   lib/armeabi/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
    21624  05-04-14 21:17   lib/armeabi/libgenerate.so
  1176064  05-04-14 21:17   lib/armeabi/libsqlcipher_android.so
   402604  05-04-14 21:17   lib/armeabi/libstlport_shared.so
  1757156  05-04-14 21:17   lib/x86/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
    17536  05-04-14 21:17   lib/x86/libgenerate.so
  3520252  05-04-14 21:17   lib/x86/libsqlcipher_android.so
   455740  05-04-14 21:17   lib/x86/libstlport_shared.so
    53292  05-04-14 21:17   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    53321  05-04-14 21:17   META-INF/CERT.SF
      776  05-04-14 21:17   META-INF/CERT.RSA
 --------                   -------
 17178672                   530 files
```

This is the error on ARM device:

```
05-04 21:21:13.377  28356-29048/com.my.app W/dalvikvm﹕ No implementation found for native Lnet/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteDatabase;.native_key ([C)V
05-04 21:21:13.377  28356-29048/com.my.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a98228)
05-04 21:21:13.447  28356-28420/com.my.app I/global﹕ In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
05-04 21:21:13.587  28356-28420/com.my.app I/global﹕ call createSocket() return a new socket.
05-04 21:21:13.767  28356-29048/com.my.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: native_key
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.native_key(Native Method)
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1948)
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:875)
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:868)
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:903)
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:914)
            at com.my.appskg.OtvorDB(skg.java:535)
            at com.my.appfsListActivity$asyncOtvorDB.doInBackground(fsListActivity.java:289)
            at com.my.appfsListActivity$asyncOtvorDB.doInBackground(fsListActivity.java:80)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

And on x86 device it opens database correctly.

```
05-04 21:22:38.494    1849-1884/com.my.app D/DeviceID.db﹕ LastError
05-04 21:22:38.874    1849-1849/com.my.app D/com.my.appfsListActivity$asyncOtvorDB﹕ onPostExecute
05-04 21:22:38.890    1849-1849/com.my.app D/fsListActivity﹕ DID.LastError:
05-04 21:22:38.890    1849-1849/com.my.app D/com.my.app.skg﹕ ZoznamCS
05-04 21:22:38.902    1849-1849/com.my.app D/cursor is﹕ net.sqlcipher.CrossProcessCursorWrapper@52aa7f30
```

This is my code to create encrypted db:

```
~/Soft/sqlcipher-2.1.1/sqlite3 db.sqlite "ATTACH DATABASE 'enc_v211.db' AS encrypted KEY '$dbkey';SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');DETACH DATABASE encrypted;"
~/Soft/sqlcipher-2.2.1/sqlcipher db.sqlite "ATTACH DATABASE 'enc_v221.db' AS encrypted KEY '$dbkey';SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');DETACH DATABASE encrypted;"
~/Soft/sqlcipher-3.1.0/sqlcipher db.sqlite "ATTACH DATABASE 'enc_v310.db' AS encrypted KEY '$dbkey';SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');DETACH DATABASE encrypted;"
```

Then I copy encrypted db to assets, and this is my code to open db:

```
 public void OpenDB() {     
        skg.logD(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName() , Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()); 

        String dbname = "enc.db";
        String dbpath = "/data/data/com.my.app/databases/";
        try {
            InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(dbname);
            String outFileName = dbpath + dbname;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);
            File databaseFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbpath + dbname);
            skg.logD("OtvorDB","getDBpath=" + databaseFile.toString());
            DID.context = context;
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, DID.db(), null);
            //database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databaseFile.getAbsolutePath(), DID.db(), null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            skg.logD("OtvorDB", e.getMessage() + e.toString() + e.getCause());
        }
```

As you can see in code, I have tried with openDatabase, and with openOrCreateDatabase too.

This devices I use for test:

> x86 - several devices in Genymotion VM
>
> ARM - 2 real devices, android emulator

App is built without error:

```
Executing tasks: [:SKG:assembleFatDebug]

Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:SKG:compileFatDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:preBuild
:SKG:preFatDebugBuild
:SKG:checkFatDebugManifest
:SKG:preArmDebugBuild
:SKG:preArmReleaseBuild
:SKG:preArmv7DebugBuild
:SKG:preArmv7ReleaseBuild
:SKG:preFatReleaseBuild
:SKG:preMipsDebugBuild
:SKG:preMipsReleaseBuild
:SKG:preX86DebugBuild
:SKG:preX86ReleaseBuild
:SKG:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71910Library UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices3159Library UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:prepareFatDebugDependencies
:SKG:compileFatDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:compileFatDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateFatDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:mergeFatDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateFatDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateFatDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:mergeFatDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:processFatDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:processFatDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:generateFatDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:ndkBuild
make: Entering directory `/Users/coudy/git/myapp/SKG/src/main/jni'
[armeabi] Install        : libdatabase_sqlcipher.so => libs/armeabi/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
[armeabi] Install        : libgenerate.so => libs/armeabi/libgenerate.so
[armeabi] Install        : libsqlcipher_android.so => libs/armeabi/libsqlcipher_android.so
[armeabi] Install        : libstlport_shared.so => libs/armeabi/libstlport_shared.so
[x86] Install        : libdatabase_sqlcipher.so => libs/x86/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
[x86] Install        : libgenerate.so => libs/x86/libgenerate.so
[x86] Install        : libsqlcipher_android.so => libs/x86/libsqlcipher_android.so
[x86] Install        : libstlport_shared.so => libs/x86/libstlport_shared.so
make: Leaving directory `/Users/coudy/git/myapp/SKG/src/main/jni'
:SKG:compileFatDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:preDexFatDebug UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:dexFatDebug UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:processFatDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:SKG:validateDebugSigning
:SKG:packageFatDebug
:SKG:assembleFatDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 15.848 secs
```

p.s: I have tried to post this message on SQLCipher user google group, but I don't have permission for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replied to your question on the mailing list thread [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlcipher/eGhuB6uqZtQ/kf0ngypa_34J).